# GRUB Chainloader saying "error: invalid signature"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, dell, windows-10

I'm trying to use GRUB to boot a Windows USB as my computer just seems to not want to. I've tried to do the chainloader command from the GRUB console on boot up (e.g. `chainloader (hd1)/bootmgr`) but when I press enter, it throws out the "error: invalid signature," I know it can read the file system because ls (hd1)/ shows me the files on there. I've seen many answers stating that the problem is that the computer is using UEFI but my computer doesn't support UEFI (as seen by efibootmgr) which is odd, I've already preformed a "Boot Repair" ([log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fndnbj6vS2/)) but I still get error:invalid signature, any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Years ago Ubuntu converted to hybrid ISO that could be used on DVDs or image copied (dd, not just copy) to flash drive. But Windows is not a hybrid ISO, so you cannot directly boot it as a copy on flash drive. Normally best to create Windows installers from another Windows system.

Comment: What would be a good way to create a Windows installer on Ubuntu then? It seems dd doesn't work if it can't make a Windows installer.

Comment: Never done it, but see these: Make Windows bootable installer from Ubuntu
http://onetransistor.blogspot.ch/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328513&p=13557011#post13557011 & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu